# CSS [draggable] elements

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, css-selectors

```
[draggable] {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Is the [draggable] referring to any draggable element? If not what does it mean? I see the user-select is being set so that text is not accidentally selected from what the comments tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means disable user-select for **ANY** element having attribute `draggable`, it's an attribute selector to be more specific,  you can use  `element [attr=val]` where it will target an element, having that `attr` `val` pair.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BC8yE/)

---

You can also use something like `element [attr]` but this selector wont check the value of the attribute, but you can select a specific element having that attribute regardless of the value.